Get rid of shuffle/CartesianRDD from the execution plan - Spark Structured Streaming
I have the following problem:
There is a Spark Structured Streaming query that runs forEachBatch and executes custom Python code as arrowOptimized Spark UDFs. The code is relatively complex. The general idea is:

Read a stream from Kafka
Join the stream to a small lookup table (batch) within forEachBatch
Divide the values into 2 groups, based on the value from the lookup table
Run processing using an arrowOptimized UDF on group A
Divide the group B into multiple DFs (using collect() and for loop - I am aware it is suboptimal but it is unavoidable here)
Run regular Spark transformations on each of DFs from group B
Union transformed group A and all DFs from group B.
Write to Delta.

The execution plan looks like this:

An alternative flow, using regular Python generates a very similar yet simpler plan:

Plan 1 works way better for the mentioned Group A and slightly worse for group B.
I would like to simplify plan 1, so that it is more similar to plan 2.

why do you need to do "7. Union transformed group A and all DFs from group B."? If it's union then why not write each dataframe directly to delta table? I.e. skip 7 and goto 8 directly, just write each individual df instead of one uber-unioned-df.
